# Multiple password forms + password completion

Tags: firefox, passwords

On a website I'm working we have an onsite login and a private login, the problem I'm having is that Firefox doesn't seem to be able to differentiate between these login forms.

Does anybody know how I can make clear that these are different logins?

I already tried giving the form fields different names and ids, ex: onsite_login and login but without success.

**edit:** my form-tags are not being mixed up, they aren't even on the same page

The two forms on the different pages

```
<form method="post" action="/en/login/1">
<fieldset>
    <p>
        <input type="hidden" value="login" name="form"/>
        <input type="hidden" value="en" name="redirect"/>
        <label for="onsite_username">Username<abbr title="Required ">*</abbr></label>
        <input type="text" class="input-text" maxlength="255" value="" name="onsite_username" id="onsite_username"/>
        <label for="onsite_password">Password<abbr title="Required ">*</abbr></label>
        <input type="password" class="input-password" maxlength="255" value="" name="onsite_password" id="onsite_password"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Log in" name="submit" class="input-submit"/>
    </p>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

and

```
<form method="post" action="">
<fieldset>
    <input type="hidden" value="login" name="form"/>
    <div>
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" class="input-text" value="" name="username" id="username"/>
    </div><div>
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="input-password" value="" name="password" id="password"/>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Aanmelden" class="input-submit"/>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Maybe some code paste would be helpful as I agree with dragonlord21!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently this is not possible due to the way Firefox stores its passwords.

A password-manager entry is stored with the following data

- The username (encrypted and secured with Firefox Master Password).
- The password (encrypted and secured with Firefox Master Password).
- The hostname of the webpage containing the login form.
- The hostname of the webpage to which the form data has been submitted.

Thus Firefox does not distinguish between the two loginfields on my page.

Comment: Thank you! I was going nuts! Before finding this answer I had scrambled the form and input names/ids with no luck!. I cannot believe that we don't have a more intelligent password manager in this day and age.

Answer (score 1):

I've not yet heard about a multiple form problem in Firefox.
But it could be that Firefox mixed up your 2 login forms if there is another tag around that is not closed properly.
I've had that problem myself with `<p>` tags and a not properly closed `<div>` around it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure.. but try to give them a different ID like `<form method="POST" action="#" id="login1">`

Comment: tried giving the form different id's, didn't work
tried giving the form elements complete different names and id's, same result